# Can spring boot have multiple @SpringBootTest classes?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

I have a use case where i want to segregate the test cases and for that, i want to use 2 test classes, each with `@SpringBootTest` annotation to start up the server as required.

I have tried doing so, but looks like this doesn't work.
I am unable to find it in the docs to confirm that it is really not supported.

Comment: Yes, what is issue you are facing.

Comment: can share what you did yet and some code snippet